# ldap connection timing out

Tags: c#, iis, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have an asp.net version 4 application which is using windows authentication for security this works fine on a machine running iis 6 windows server 2003, but when migrating to iis 7 windows server 2008 r2 standard I get the following error:

> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.ConstructResponse(Int32
>   messageId, LdapOperation operation,
>   ResultAll resultType, TimeSpan
>   requestTimeOut, Boolean
>   exceptionOnTimeOut)

iis authentication is enabled for both windows and asp.net impersonation, with the others being disabled (I have tried various combinations with no success).  This is running in its own .net 4 app pool and I have tried both integrated and classic managed pipeline modes.  From the event log I can see this code is causing the time out problem:

```
var searchResponse = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(searchRequest);
```

Am I missing a trick here?

Comment: You sure that you posted the error message?

Comment: Exception Details: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: An operation error occurred.

Comment: How do you know it's a timeout problem? Do you have more details? Stack trace for example?